# How to overwrite data in div under ngFor in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a List of integer array type values. The value is displayed using `*ngFor` as shown:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of values; let i = index">
  <div> 
     <div *ngFor="let subitem of item;" style="display:block">
       <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar" id="progress" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" [style.width.%] = "subitem">
              {{subitem}}
            </div> 
       </div>
       <br>
   </div>
</div>
```

I do not want the `div` to be created over and over again. I want to put a delay and show the contents of the list in a single `div`. That is: the values in the div will be replaced after a delay.(say 1 iteration)

Comment: do you want to show a progress bar using *ngFor?

Comment: why don't you use ng-template instead

Comment: i want to display as in this link https://interview.mapsted.com/software/sorting-example.mp4

Answer (score 2):

U can achieve the same with following code.

```
    <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress-bar" id="progress" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" 
                 aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" [style.width.%] = "subitem">
          {{subitem}}
        </div> 
    </div>
```

In typescript we can have the following code.

```
  for(let i=0; i <= item.length; i++) {
     setTimeout((subitem) => {
        this.subitem = subitem;
      },i * yourTimeOfIntervale, item[i])
  }
```

Comment: I have a list of integer array. Using the above for loop doesn't work for me. My list look like {[4,2,1,5,6],[1,2,4,5,6]}.

Comment: i cross verified its printing sequentially 1,2,3,4,5,6.
I may need more details and also cross check the variables once

Comment: i want to display as in this link interview.mapsted.com/software/sorting-example.mp4

Comment: my API returning a list of integer array to angular. The list actually records the sorting iteration step as an integer array.